# ¿Como puedo cambiar de directorio en azure function apps de manera local? [Node JS]

Tags: nodejs, typescript, backend, azure

Estoy trabajando con function apps de Azure usando node js y typescript, todo corriendo de manera local.

Por defecto las function apps se crean en el directorio raíz pero quiero cambiarlas dentro de un directorio llamado src.

Intenté cambiar la propiedad scriptFile en el function.json pero no funciona.

*"scriptFile": "**../**../dist/src/HttpUsers/index.js"*

También, cambié la propiedad rootDir a ./src en el tsconfig.json pero tampoco funciona

El resultado en la consola cuando corro *npm run* es "No jobs functions found":

**¿Alguien sabe como puedo cambiar al directorio src correctamente las function apps?**

Comment: Hola ignacio. Estás en stackoveflow en español.  Traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada. Saludos.

Comment: First: use Spanish, second: **don't use images for code**, third: Por favor leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Saludos